# Add margin to title in collapsed Collapsing Toolbar Layout

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to add a margin to where my Title in the collapsed state starts. 
I have a Button which overlays where the title is starting:

[image]

I have tried using a style with left margin in `app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance` but that is not working either. Following is my `.xml` file. ( Note, the back button is a text view and not an action bar.) The title is being added programmatically.

```xml
<style name ="collapsingToolbarTextCollapsed">
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">42dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">42dp</item>
        <item name="paddingStart">42dp</item>
    </style>
```

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profile_main_expanded_back_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:elevation="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back_button"
        android:foreground="@drawable/back_button" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/collapsingToolbarTextCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_avatar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="profile picture"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder_user"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following to rectify the situation :

- Remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from app bar layout and collapsing toolbar layout
- Add `paddingLeft` to the Toolbar

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profile_main_expanded_back_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:elevation="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back_button"
        android:foreground="@drawable/back_button" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="left"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_avatar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="profile picture"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder_user"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:paddingLeft="42dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not following a proper pattern. Coordinator Layout always has first child AppBarLayout and second child Any of ScrollView/NestedScrollView/RecyclerView with behaviour.

Don't use a separate view for back button, you can enable back button of toolbar using the below code

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.htab_toolbar); 
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

//this line shows back button
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and remove your text, which you using to show back button like below.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

      app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/collapsingToolbarTextCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_avatar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="profile picture"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder_user"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: This makes the textview with id profile_main_expanded_back_button to disappear when the bar is collapsed. How do I tackle that?

Comment: Updated the answer, check now @fireball.1